# Debugging CUDA with memcheck, using the JCuda wrapper

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, memcheck, jcuda

I am working on an image segmentation program which uses JCuda. The project is a Maven project, the dependencies for JCuda however are stored in dll files and are not managed with maven. Since I got a runtime error in my Cuda kernel (*.ptx), which is invoked by Jcuda, I want to start to debug, which is relatively difficult using a Java wrapper for Cuda. Thus, I want to use “memcheck”, which requires to have a *.bat file which invokes my Java program. This is the point where I get lost. I do not manage to create a runnable jar file, which I can run with the java command in my *.bat file. My Question is, is there another way I could debug my Cuda code, but without creating a runnable jar file? –If not, how can I create a runnable jar file from maven?

I am aware that other people had that question too, but no answer worked for me, which makes me suspect that the dll files have to do with it. I tried to package the project with maven (maven built… -> goal: package). When I navigate to the target directory where my jar file was created via my command prompt the program does not run:

[java in cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhMVQ.png)

The reply means that no main manifest attribute can be found. Here is the snapshot of my pom file which is supposed to define the main class:

[Build in pom file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUl0W.png)

Thank you for your help. This is my first post here on stack overflow, so please point out inconsistencies in my question.

Comment: Instead of linking to images, could you please copy-paste the relevant parts. Links may get broken over time. Thanks.

Comment: True; unfortunately I do not have that option as a new user here.

Comment: What do you mean? You can paste the code and the output as text and use the formatter to make it look nice. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Hey, yes I understand, thank you, I was talking about adding images now though, not code.

Comment: btw, I'm recommending you to try out Mavenized version of JCuda - it could simplify it a bit https://github.com/MysterionRise/mavenized-jcuda

Comment: There may be some discussion/clarification necessary. If this can not be disucssed here, you can consider asking about this at the [JCuda forum](http://forum.byte-welt.net/forumdisplay.php?f=90&langid=2) (even in German ;-)). But a basic hint: When you want to run the program with `java -jar`, then there has to be a "main class" defined in the manifest. Simpler (for your case) might be to simply add the JAR to the classpath, and execute the class that contains your main method, roughly: `java -cp yourJar.jar;jcudaJar.jar yourpackage.YourClassWIthMainMethod`.